# SUM area of intersecting polygon and circle. Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Suppose I have the following overlays drawn on a google map. I would like to get the area covered by B + C.

[image: Map with intersecting circle and polygon]

My plan is to use [google overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) computeArea() method to get the area of the polygon, and just use the formula for area of a circle but how do I account for their intersection? Is there a way to do this in the google maps api?

Comment: did you find a working example with Google Maps Api? I made a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbs2h59e/5/)

Comment: Above JSFiddle link is not working, do you have another ?